# Convolution: characteristic-functions

Tags: convolution, characteristic-functions

Let $\alpha>0$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

$g(t):=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(t)$ and $h_{\alpha}(t):=\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(t)$.

The convolution is:

$g\ast h_{\alpha}(t)=\int g(x)h_{\alpha}(t-x)dx$
$=\int \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(t-x)dx$
$=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{t}1 dx$
$=\frac{1}{\alpha} t$

But actually the solution is: $\frac{1}{\alpha} t  \mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha)}(t)$.

Does anyone see where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the integral you wrote
$$\int \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(t-x)dx$$

we have two restrictions

$$\begin{cases}x\geq 0\\0\leq t-x\leq a\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow \begin{cases}x\geq 0\\t-a\leq x\leq t.\end{cases} $$

There are 3 cases. When $t<0$ there are no solutions and the integrant is zero.

If $0\leq t\leq \alpha $, then $t-\alpha\leq 0 $ and the system above gives $0\leq x\leq t$ and the intergal becomes $\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{t}1 dx = \frac{1}{\alpha} t$ as you wrote.

If $t>\alpha$ then $t-\alpha>0$ and the system gives $t-a\leq x\leq t$. The integral then becomes
$$\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{t-a}^{t}1 dx = \frac{1}{\alpha} (t - (t-\alpha)) = 1$$
Thus
$$g\ast h_{\alpha}(t)=\frac{1}{\alpha} t  \mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(t)  + \mathbf{1}_{(\alpha,\infty)}(t).$$

Answer (score 1):

Following your computation, just being a bit more cautious about the connection between the upper limit of the integral and the definition of $h_\alpha$ yields
$$
g\ast h_{\alpha}(t)=\int_{x=0}^t g(x)h_{\alpha}(t-x)dx
=\int_{x=0}^t \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(x)\frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(t-x)dx\\
=\frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{x=0}^t \mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(t-x)dx
=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{y=0}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(y)dy
= \frac{t}\alpha \quad \mathrm{for}\; t\leq\alpha
$$
where we used the simple substitution $y=t-x$. When $t$ goes over $\alpha$, the integrand becomes zero so for $t>\alpha$ we can write the last integral above as
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{y=0}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(y)dy
=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{y=0}^{\alpha} \mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(y)dy
+\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{y=\alpha}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(y)dy
=1
\quad \mathrm{for}\; t>\alpha
$$
the last integral being zero.
If you want to put the above into one formula, you can write (as in the answer by Dosidis)
$$
g\ast h_{\alpha}(t)=\frac{t}{\alpha} \mathbf{1}_{[0,\alpha]}(t) + \mathbf{1}_{(\alpha,\infty]}(t).
$$